# Create a UIView title of a push view using the index of an array

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, titlebar, nsrangeexception

I have a `UITableView` that pushes to a `UIView` when the user taps the `UITableViewCell`. I want to make the title of the push view the text from the cell that the push view is coming from. I am trying to declare an `NSUInteger` when the row is selected to create a string with objectAtIndex. it is my understanding that `objectAtIndex` accepts type `NSUInteger`. This hasn't really been working for me.

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//get index number
NSNumber *selRow = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:indexPath.row];
NSUInteger rows = (NSUInteger)selRow;
NSLog(@"%@",rows); //this outputs correctly
NSString *pushTitle = [[self.WorkoutListArray objectAtIndex:rows] stringValue];  //error on this line

//declares a new view controller when something is selected -- uses story board to initialize
WorkoutPushViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WorkoutPush"];

//when selected a new view is pushed
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];

//adds a title to the push view
newView.title = pushTitle;
}
@end
```

I am getting an

> NSRangeExcpetion error

when I try to declare the string. I've tried a few ways to declare an `NSString` from the `NSArray` but haven't had luck yet.  I hope my question was clear :)

Comment: Print the `self.WorkoutListArray`

Comment: @Bannings I used NSLog(@"%@", self.WorkoutListArray); it printed (
    "<SingleWorkout: 0x7fea79525fb0>",
    "<SingleWorkout: 0x7fea7952bdb0>"
)
Thanks for pointing this out. any Idea how I can fix this?

Comment: @Bannings i figured out the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that the object I was trying to print had a name and date property. (sorry for making that dumb mistake) The following code does exactly what I wanted it to do.

```
NSString *pushTitle = [[self.WorkoutListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] workoutName];

//set the title
newView.title = pushTitle;
```

Thanks for the help and patience.